# how shall i remove unwanted space from my UI

Tags: android-layout, android

this is my UI of my app and it works perfectly on devices with screen size from 3.2 inch to 4.0 inch but above that it shows unwanted space above capacitive buttons and the last line of buttons.

Any suggestion on how shall i remove it. There is no such issue on devices with screen size below 4.0 inch.

[here is link to screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wHealzmk4JTUJXSlFORFlDYXc/edit?usp=sharing). here is my xml code

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-bold"
android:background="#EAC14D"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:layout_marginTop="55dp"

>




<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/insert"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundeditext"

    android:hint="0"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/floor"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sin"
        android:id="@+id/sin"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cos"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/cos"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tan"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/tan"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="floor"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/floor"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abs"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/abs"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="rand"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/random"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="asin"
        android:id="@+id/asin"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="acos"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/acos"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="atan"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/atan"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ceil"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/ceil"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="^2"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/square"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sqrt"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/sqrt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sinh"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/sinh"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cosh"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/cosh"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="tanh"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/tanh"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fact"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/fact"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="^3"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/cube"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="cbrt"
        android:background="@drawable/normal_calculator_button_press"
        android:id="@+id/cbrt"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/seven"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/eight"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/nine"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="%"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/mod"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="&lt;"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/mul"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="/"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ln"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/ln"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="log"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/log"

        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/zero"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="."
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:id="@+id/dot"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="("
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/cbracket"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=")"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/obracket"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/equal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pi"
        android:background="@drawable/programmer_button_pressed"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/pie"
        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_layout_normal_calc_bottom_textsize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should play with `layout_weight` attribute on the last container. Make it equals to 1 to completely expand to the remaining room. (and set its height to 0dp)

Comment: by setting height to 0 means setting android:layout_height="0"??

Comment: No, `0dp` -> `android:layout_height="0dp"`. If you don't do this, it could behave weiredly with weight attribute

Comment: I have set this android:layout_height="0dp" on each button or in linearlayout??

Comment: You have to expand the last container (the gray one). So you should set this weight to that last container

Comment: i did that and it hides my complete row and gives me error

Comment: Right... So you don't have a container (a view group containing all the grey buttons). Therefore, try to set weigth at 1 and height at 0 for each horizontal grey LinearLayout

Comment: i just did that and it looks soemthing like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3wHealzmk4JcVZZREpNMlVtU0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Buttons should have `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: extremely thanks to you, finally it worked. Thanks you very much sir